# ERROR [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'globalThis.localStorage.getItem')]

Tags: expo, supabase

I am trying to just select everything from a table from supabase. When I perform my fetch function, this is thrown and I dont know why.I have my URL and Key set into my supbase.js file.

[picture of fetch function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLqca.png)

Answer (score 0):

Weights seems to be your data type.

Try this instead:

```
const {data: Weights, error} = await supabase.from('Weights').select('*');
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supabase parses the response and returns an object, so you don't need to parse it by yourself. Trying to parse what is already an object throws an error, and that is what was happening in your case.

The following should work!

```js
const {data, error} = await supabase.from('Weights').select('*');
console.log(data);
return data;
```